# pdfbox is not fully installed

Tags: javascript, java, pdfbox

[image]

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
```

Hello I installed pdfbox recently but there is a problem when importing the library in the last line import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream; **edit** is not resolved even though I installed everthing here is my library.

[image: if there anything missing please tell me]

Answer (score 2):

That's because PDPageContentStream is in the `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel` package. It seems you're using code that was written for PDFBox 1.8. And you only need two jar files here, pdfbox and fontbox.